# Difference between fs.defaultFS and fs.default.name

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, configuration-files, namenode

I know both these properties are related to namenode. But what is the actual difference between them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Property `fs.default.name` has been deprecated and replaced by
`fs.defaultFS`.

Answer (score 3):

Both are same only. **fs.default.name** is deprecated property of **fs.defaultFS**.

You can find more deprecated properties and new property [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html)