# regarding core-ste.xml file entries with start-dfs.sh and map reduce task - Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Am new to big data modules and am running hadoop on ubuntu.

1. for map reduce jobs, the below entry from core-site.xml needs to be suppressed

   fs.default.name
       hdfs://localhost:8020
2. start-dfs.sh does not execute with the above entry suppressed.

kindly assist and do update if multiple core-site.xml files or entries are permitted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between fs.defaultFS and fs.default.name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480847/difference-between-fs-defaultfs-and-fs-default-name)

Answer (score 0):

`fs.defaultFS` is the preferred property over the deprecated `fs.default.name` . One of them is required, and they cannot be "suppressed".

If you define multiple matching properties in the XML, only one will be used.

You can't have multiple files with the same name in the same hadoop config directory, anyway. This includes  "core-site.xml"

Comment: Thanks Dear!!! Any workaround???